# Trigger HTTP POST firebase cloud function with HTTP Native Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, firebase, http-post

Im triying to trigger an http function through my Ionic 2 app using HTTP from ionic native.

(function below)

```
HTTPTrigger(){
  let url = "https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/addMessage" 
  let body = JSON.stringify({text: "Hola Mundo"}) ;
  this.http.post(url,body)
}
```

If i trigger the same function thru an URL in the browser everything works perfect.

```
https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/addMessage?text=Hola Mundo
```

The cloud function is from a Firebase "Function Samples":

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {  
   const original =  req.query.text;
   admin.database().ref('/userProfile/').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
   res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
  });
});
```

So I figured I´m doing something wrong.

Thank you guys for your help

Comment: It's not clear to me what's going wrong here.  Can you clarify exactly what you're doing, what the result should be, and what isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: Im trying to trigger a Firebase Cloud Function through ionic HTTP post method in my client app, the cloud function get the request  (Hola Mundo ) and writes the word "Hola Mundo" in to my firebase db if i trigger it through the browser.

Comment: Is there an error in the console?  Right now you're just saying it doesn't work, which isn't really enough information to work with.